# Syslog not logging

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

My syslog setup has been happily running for years, and suddenly I cannot log anything at all.

With the **default** configuration I test logging by running a PHP script:

```
php -r "syslog(LOG_NOTICE,'Test message');"
```

Also, using the logger command:

```
/usr/bin/logger -s "Test message"
```

On an identical healthy server bother commands write lines to `/var/log/messages`. On the bad server I get nothing:

- `rsyslogd` service is running
- Nothing is logged to `/var/log/messages` except the systemd restart messages
- Running `rsyslogd -nd` in the foreground, I get no debug output at all when the above command is run.
- Running `rsyslogd -N1` to check syntax I get no config errors

I'm running rsyslogd 8.24.0-34.el7 on CentOS 7

What could be preventing the system from receiving messages?

---

Update: After resorting to a machine restart this fixed itself.

It also flushed out a bunch of repeated errors from the previous days like this:

```
rsyslogd: sd_journal_get_cursor() failed: 'Cannot assign requested address'  [v8.24.0-34.el7]
rsyslogd: imjournal: journal reloaded... [v8.24.0-34.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

> What could be preventing the system from receiving messages?
> may be no free disk space available

> rsyslogd: sd_journal_get_cursor() failed: 'Cannot assign requested address'  [v8.24.0-34.el7]
> rsyslogd: imjournal: journal reloaded... [v8.24.0-34.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]

The error appears when the logs are rotated.

This is a bug in rsyslog v8.24.0-34.el7   - update to the latest current version.

or, you may comment it out in the /etc/rsyslog.conf file

```
$ModLoad imjournal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state
```

Add

```
module (load= "imjournal" StateFile= "imjournal.state" WorkAroundJournalBug= " on")
```

and restart service rsyslog